# Using is_unique validation rule with two fields?

Tags: validation, codeigniter

I have two input fields in a form. I need to check if both of them are unique in a table in which they are inserted. How can I perform this check in codeigniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes its really easy with CI form validation you need to set is_unique to check unique value in table

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|is_unique[users.username]');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
```

in above example you can see is_unique table name and column name of table to check unique value as parameter

here the document link you can read 
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference

Comment: will this set of rules check for the uniqueness of the username and email pair in the table.

Comment: you can put any column name of your database table to check uniqueness

Comment: Sir @umefarooq please let me know that is it possible to apply is_unique on multiple columns?
Please guide if you have the key.